# JavaScript: Text "submit" link?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the the following code and want to use a hyper link to submit my form.

```
<form name="form_signup" id="form_signup" method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<input type="submit" value="Go to Step 2" name="completed" /> or <a onclick="javascript:this.form.submit();">Proceed without uploading</a></span>
</form>
```

However, my hyperlink submit doesn't work. It just keeps me on the same page.

Question: any idea why my link submit text doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The `this` in your `"javascript:this.form.submit();"` refers to the `<a>` tag, which has no `form` property, resulting in a JavaScript error.

The smallest required change, but far from the most elegant, would be something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('form_signup').submit();">...</a>
```

Comment: The code above still doesn't work. It doesn't submit the form.

Comment: Interesting, does *anything* happen? Refreshed the page?

Comment: Not sure what could be wrong, maybe you could edit your post and paste the current code you're trying with .. I created a dummy page with the suggested change and it does submit.

Comment: Shouldn't it go into the onclick event?

Comment: @Tedd, good question ;-) I guess I got distracted by you using the "javascript:..." notation, which works if put inside the href. Neither is "elegant", but either should work. By either I mean: href="javascript:document.getElementById('form_signup').submit();" or onclick="document.getElementById('form_signup').submit();"